# In Rails, with cookie-based session store, are session and cookies the same thing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http

I've always been using the cookie-based session store, and never even knew about [Cookies](http://api.rubyonrails.com/classes/ActionController/Cookies.html) until now. So is there any situation where I'd need the cookies hash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cookies hash definitely has value in Rails apps.  **You should use cookies to store values on the client side that you want to remember between sessions.**

A 'remember me' token is a great example.  If you want to allow a user to be auto logged in when they visit your site, just store a persistent cookie with some user tamper-proof value (like a unique hash or guid (good) that maps to that user's row in your db but isn't hackable like just using a plain old integer user id (bad)).  Then, when a user visits your site, you can check the cookies hash for a remember me token and, if found, do a lookup in your db and log the user in if a match is found. This is a very common practice.

If you need/want to store plaintext values in the client side cookie, but don't want the user to be able to futz with the values, just store a hash of that value in a companion cookie and salt the hash with some value unknown to the user.  Then you just need to compute the salted hash of the plaintext value received from the client cookie and compare it against the hashed value also passed from the client cookie.  If they match, you can trust it.

Answer (score 1):

any situation that might use a cookie seems to be equally well served by the cookie session store. the rails cookie session store is secure in the sense that the end-user can read the session data but cannot modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I got really confused about the relation of sessions with cookies while thinking how to implement remember me for OpenID login... which actually doesn't differ from doing it for password-based login. But that wasn't my code, it came from the restful-authentication plugin, and there's nothing like thinking through the whole process on your own.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't store anything you don't want the user to see or change in cookie. If you store a member ID then the user could easily change the value and pretend to be someone else. Cookies are also sent with every single request to your web server including image, JS and CSS requests. If you are storing lots of information in cookies, this could have an impact on speed.

Cookie-based sessions (in a general context, I can't say I know what Rails does) means your session variables are associated with a session ID which is randomly generated. This ID, and only the ID, is returned to the the user as a cookie. This allows you to associate the users request (because you have session ID cookies)  with the user's sessions. This is safer because it would be very difficult for someone to guess the ID of another user's session.

Comment: The actual information in a Rails cookie session is stored in the cookie, so there is a 4k limit on what can be stored in the session. Keep sensitive information out of the cookie session, or use a different session method.

Comment: That 4k limit isn't enforced in some browsers, or at least not entirely properly. Ran into a problem on an app recently where Firefox was sending a 16K cookie. It was gross.