# Hartl Rails tutorial tests failing at the end of section 9.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, railstutorial.org

In [this section](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#sec-friendly_forwarding) I'm supposed to restrict the user to edit and update only his own profile. All my tests pass up to this point, except for this one:

```
     describe "as wrong user" do
       let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
       let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
       before { sign_in user }

       describe "visiting Users#edit page" do
         before { visit edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
         it { should_not have_selector('title', text: full_title('Edit user')) }
       end

       describe "submitting a PUT request to the Users#update action" do
         before { put user_path(wrong_user) }
         specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
       end
     end
```

Specifically the last part, the redirection, this is what I get when I run the test:

```
  1) Authentication authorization as wrong user submitting a PUT request to the Users#update action 
     Failure/Error: specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
       Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/> but was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/signin>
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_spec.rb:86:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

But in the website, when I attempt to do this same thing it works just fine, the user is redirected to the root_path of the application.

Comment: I'm not sure which test describe is broken. sign_in test method is defined ? See Listing 9.6. 
spec/support/utilities.rb

Comment: I was gonna close this question but couldn't because I closed others, the problem was that by placing the private methods before the rest of my methods in my users controller i privatized all the methods

Comment: I decided to modify my question since I ran into a different snag and this one I can't seem to find the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked out your code from [your Github repo](https://github.com/8vius/sample_app), and it seems that your modifications to **app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb** are responsible for your failing tests.  Compare [your file](https://github.com/8vius/sample_app/blob/master/app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb) to [the tutorial's file](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed/blob/master/app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb).  You are using a `session` hash instead of a `cookies` hash in your methods.  I fixed your `"submitting a PUT request to the Users#update action"` and `"submitting a DELETE request to the Users#destroy action"` errors by changing the code thus:

**app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb**

```
module SessionsHelper
  # ...

  def sign_in(user)
    # session[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    # session.delete(:remember_token)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  def current_user
    # @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(session[:remember_token])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end

  # ...
end
```

There was an exercise in Rails 3.0 version of The Rails Tutorial where [you replaced the `cookies` hash completely with a `session` hash](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial?version=3.0#sec%3asign_in_out_exercises), but I recall never being able to do it properly, and it [doesn't seem to be in the 3.2 version](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#sec-updating_deleting_exercises) anyway, so it would seem that you're safest sticking with a `cookies` hash in this file.

Comment: It's referenced in the chapter 8 exercises actually, in a Rails Cast, and then he switches to using it in section 10 so I just switched to it. That fixed it thanks for taking the time to do that. And also, since we're on the subject, what is better? Using the cookies or the session variable?

Comment: This is stuff I had to learn too, but it would seem that ["the main difference is that the session data stored on the server, whereas the cookies are stored on the client (browser)"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7743670/567863) and that ["you should use cookies to store values on the client side that you want to remember between sessions"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/312636/567863).  So, for the purposes of a remember token, the `cookies` hash seems most appropriate.

Comment: Then the problem there arises that you can modify the cookies, so for securing the user it would be better to save it in the session, no?

Comment: Good question...unfortunately, I can't really offer opinions apart from what I have read elsewhere (like the content in the links above).  You may want to poll the experts on StackOverflow by posing this as a separate question if you can't find an answer elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Is this code in Listing 9.6 written in your code?

```
# Sign in when not using Capybara as well.
cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
```

1. Capybara behaves like a browser, so it can receive some cookies from rails app.
2. Capybara can test app like operating a browser using 'fill_in' and 'visit'.
3. To issue "PUT /users/1" request in Capybara, it needs to go "/users/1/edit", then click "edit" link. 
   But your rails app doesn't allow user to access other user, which is passed in previous test example.
4. We can't issue "PUT /users/1" directly in Capybara. Instead, we need to use "put". 
   Rspec can't receive any cookies from app. So we need to set cookies as Listing 9.6.
5. If test example issues "PUT /users/1" request without remember_token in cookies, it will be redirected to sign in page as a non-signed in user. But this test intends that it is redirected to root page as signed in user send a put request to other user's resource directly.

Comment: Yes that is included in my code, the test for the DELETE fails the same way.